# Regex for a pattern XXYYZZ

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to validate a string which should follow the pattern `XXYYZZ` where X, Y, Z can be any letter a-z, A-Z or 0-9.

Example of valid strings:

```
RRFFKK
BB7733
WWDDMM
5599AA
```

Not valid:

```
555677
AABBCD
```

For now I am splitting the string using the regex `(?<=(.))(?!\\1)` and iterating over the resulting array and checking if each substring has a length of 2.

```
String str = "AABBEE";
boolean isValid = checkPattern(str);

public static boolean checkPattern(String str) {
   String splited = str.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");
   for (String s : splited) {
       if (s.length() != 2) {
         return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

I would like to replace my way of checking with `String#matches` and get rid of the loop, but can't come up with a valid regex. Can some one help what to put in `someRegex` in the below snippet?

```
public static boolean checkPattern(String str) {
    return str.matches(someRegex);
}
```

Comment: Can `X`, `Y` or `Z` be identical? Is `BBAABB` valid?

Comment: No. Valid strings consist of three different characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```java
s.matches("(\\p{Alnum})\\1(?!\\1)(\\p{Alnum})\\2(?!\\1|\\2)(\\p{Alnum})\\3")
```

See the [regex demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd9wud6r).

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string (it is implicit in `String#matches`) - the start of string
- `(\p{Alnum})\1` - an alphanumeric char (captured into Group 1) and an identical char right after
- `(?!\1)` - the next char cannot be the same as in Group 1
- `(\p{Alnum})\2` - an alphanumeric char (captured into Group 2) and an identical char right after
- `(?!\1|\2)` - the next char cannot be the same as in Group 1 and 2
- `(\p{Alnum})\3` - an alphanumeric char (captured into Group 3) and an identical char right after
- `\z` - (implicit in `String#matches`) - end of string.

RegexPlanet test results:

[image]

Comment: It's really nice to see an answer with a detailed explanation. :)

Answer (score 6):

Since you know a valid pattern will always be six characters long with three pairs of equal characters which are different from each other, a short series of explicit conditions may be simpler than a regex:

```java
public static boolean checkPattern(String str) {
   return str.length() == 6 &&
          str.charAt(0) == str.chatAt(1) &&
          str.charAt(2) == str.chatAt(3) &&
          str.charAt(4) == str.chatAt(5) &&
          str.charAt(0) != str.charAt(2) &&
          str.charAt(0) != str.charAt(4) &&
          str.charAt(2) != str.charAt(4);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is much more simple than using regexps, but the OP also [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440127/regex-for-a-pattern-xxyyzz#comment115695198_65440127) that _Valid strings consist of three different characters._ (I didn't downvote, but noticed that this answer score decreased by 1)

Comment: @fluffy good catch, thanks! I missed that restriction. I've edited my answer to address that too

Comment: Thank you. I have not thaught about this simple way.

Comment: @nopens If you're going to use Mureinik's answer, you can also optimize its readability by extracting all `charAt` calls to their respective variables (say, `final char c0 = str.charAt(0);`) that would both be less error-prone in the future and would also cache the characters into local variables (it would also save on time a little, not really a good win for `String` but can work with any other `CharSequence` implementations too that may have `.charAt` access time not _O(1)_ as `String` has.)

Answer (score 6):

Would the following work for you?

```
^(([A-Za-z\d])\2(?!.*\2)){3}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zdnmSe/6)

---

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(`- Open 1st capture group.

  - `(` - Open 2nd capture group.

    - `[A-Za-z\d]` - Any alphanumeric character.
    - `)` - Close 2nd capture group.
  - `\2` - Match exactly what was just captured.
  - `(?!.*\2)` - Negative lookahead to make sure the same character is not used elsewhere.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `{3}` - Repeat the above three times.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Comment: (You could make the outer group non capturing and use `\1`) but nice ++

Comment: @TheFourthBird, thank you. Would the non-capturing group impact performance for the better?

Comment: In theory I think there is 1 group value less to keep track off. But the data is a string of 6 chars, and if there would be a big difference I can not tell.

Comment: @Thefourthbird this attempt at simplification won't work (try the demo to prove it to yourself) because dropping the outer capturing group would make the `{3}` apply only to the last set of parentheses instead of to the whole pair of chars.

Comment: @arielf I think it works right https://regex101.com/r/b77xpz/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thanks, You're right. It is simpler this way.
It wasn't obvious from the original description. For the record: the full simplified regex which works is:
`^(?:([A-Za-z\d])\1(?!.*\1)){3}$`

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's another solution that uses regex and streams in combination.

- It breaks up the pattern into groups of two characters.
- keeps the distinct groups.
- and returns `true` if the count is 3.

```
String[] data = { "AABBBB", "AABBCC", "AAAAAA","AABBAA", "ABC", "AAABCC",
        "RRABBCCC" };
String pat = "(?:\\G(.)\\1)+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pat);

for (String str : data) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
    boolean isValid = m.results().map(MatchResult::group).distinct().count() == 3;
    System.out.printf("%8s  ->  %s%n",
            str, isValid ? "Valid" : "Not Valid");
}
```

Prints

```
  AABBBB  ->  Not Valid
  AABBCC  ->  Valid
  AAAAAA  ->  Not Valid
  AABBAA  ->  Not Valid
     ABC  ->  Not Valid
  AAABCC  ->  Not Valid
RRABBCCC  ->  Not Valid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a character matches with its following character and also if the count of distinct characters is `3`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(isValidPattern("RRFFKK"));
        System.out.println(isValidPattern("BBAABB"));
        System.out.println(isValidPattern("555677"));
    }

    static boolean isValidPattern(String str) {
        return str.length() == 6 &&                
                str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(1) && 
                str.charAt(2) == str.charAt(3) &&
                str.charAt(4) == str.charAt(5) &&
                str.chars().distinct().count() == 3;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
false
```

**Note:** [`String#chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars()) is available since Java-9.

Comment: `System.out.println(isValidPattern("BBAABB"));` shouldn't this return `true` ? Your output says otherwise.

Comment: @Dev-vruper - My function behaves correctly. The OP has mentioned: `Valid strings consist of three different characters.`

Comment: @Dev-vruper - No problem . It happens sometimes.